# Merging two allocated partitions w/o data loss?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I've got 5 partitions on my hard-disk and I've got two of them (side-by-side). Since I ran out on space for the first partition, I used the second partition. However, I really just want to merge these two so that the total space becomes roughly 442GB (216GB + 226GB). I don't have enough of storage to back up these files somewhere else and I don't want to lose any data in the process. Could you help me here?

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Minitool partition wizard. It will allow you to achieve this.
http://download.cnet.com/MiniTool-Partition-Wizard-Home-Edition/3000-2094_4-10962200.html

It is pretty simple. If you cannot figure out how to do it, I can expand this answer.

EDIT

Apparently, minitool wont let you merge partitions unless you purchase pro version.
I found a different software: http://download.cnet.com/Easeus-Partition-Master-Free-Edition/3000-2248_4-10863346.html

They have a tutorial for merging partitions. I will summarize the steps:
From the screenshot above, I think the partitions are adjecent on disk(unless you have manipulated the screenshot)

1. Open the tool and select your partition E:
2. Right click and select Merge Partition.
3. Choose partition G:.
4. Select the destination partition and click Ok and then Apply.
5. This should merge your partitions

You can find the full tutorial here(they also have a video):http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/merge-partition.htm

Comment: please do so, preferably with screenshots. Makes it much more useful